# Combining two input boxes into one using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-input

```
input[type="checkbox"].focus {border:0px;}<br>
input[type="text"].focus {border:0px;}
```

How can I combine the two things into one?

```
$("input[type='text'],input[type='checkbox']").focus {border:0px;}
```

Comment: Yes, this is JQuery. Can't figure it out. If I wrote the code separately, it would work. A combined code above is not working..

Comment: check my answer and let me know it i am lagging somewhere

Comment: Please edit the question and answer to include the updated code. The question isn't just for you, it's for everyone that ever comes across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this work like this you can not add CSS on the jQuery like we do in css to add css using jQuery you can use **css()** jQuery API the method is `css (propertyName, value)`

```
focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#FFFFCC");
});
```

For more information about the [jQuery CSS check this link](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='text'],input[type='checkbox']").focus() {border:0px;}
```

1. You're missing the closing double-quote in your selector.
2. `focus` returns the handler currently attached to the focus event. You want to actually *invoke* the method, so you need the empty argument list: `focus()`

Comment: Please edit the question and answer to include the updated code. The question isn't just for you, it's for everyone that ever comes across this problem.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We iterated on some code in a JS fiddle that was linked in the comments, but now that they've been hidden/deleted, I don't have the links anymore...